# Ignore safe area in safe area

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use [`safeAreaInset(edge:alignment:spacing:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/safeareainset(edge:alignment:spacing:content:)-1x9pl), to create a floating view at the bottom. The green view should ignore the bottom safe area, but this isn't working.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LinearGradient(
                colors: [.red, .blue],
                startPoint: .top,
                endPoint: .bottom
            )
            .frame(height: 1000)
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            Color.green
                .frame(height: 50)
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

Current result:

[image: Result]

How do I make the green view ignore the bottom safe area so it touches the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an [`overlay(alignment:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(alignment:content:)) after ignoring the safe area works. A view such as `Color.clear` can be used as the base.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LinearGradient(
                colors: [.red, .blue],
                startPoint: .top,
                endPoint: .bottom
            )
            .frame(height: 1000)
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            Color.clear
                .frame(height: 50)
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
                .overlay(
                    Color.green
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

And if you have content and want a background in the safe area:

```
Color.red
    .frame(height: 50)
    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
    .background(
        Color.green
    )
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Note: be careful with the 2nd version. If you use modifiers such as `clipShape` on the background, it can cause it to break again. Fix this by using `.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)` *after* you may clip or anything else which breaks this.

Comment: There is safer ways to reach the result you want without dealing with  `.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)`, if the result is important

Comment: @swiftPunk Feel free to add an answer

Answer (score 0):

Once you spoke about keyboard you add another difficulty to your original question! I just made simple code with `overlay` method it can easily converted to `ZStack` method as well! You do which way you like! Also I just add some fun on green View just for show and need refactor for sure, but that is not the part of issue or question!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var string: String = String()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let myDivider = Spacer().overlay(Color.secondary.frame(width: 1, height: 40))
        
        Color.clear
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            .overlay(
                
                ScrollView {
                    
                    ZStack {
                        
                        LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [.red, .blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                            .frame(height: 1000)
                        
                        VStack {
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            TextField("Enter youer text here ...", text: $string)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            )
            .overlay(
                Color.green
                    .overlay(HStack { Spacer(); Text("").padding(20); myDivider; Text("").padding(20); myDivider; Text("").padding(); Spacer() }.font(Font.system(.largeTitle)))
                    .frame(height: 80)
                
                
                , alignment: .bottom)
            .ignoresSafeArea(.container)
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Now the `ScrollView` has no safe area, so it's scrollable area extends past the notch. My answer from earlier was much simpler & works as intended. It's not worth trying to avoid `safeAreaInset`, as it's there for a useful use-case

Comment: Probably you are right! I can’t imagine all your project limitations and freedoms in my head because it is in your head! Trying to fix on issue would broke another limitations!